# Dynamically converting crystal report generated to pdf format by button click event

Tags: c#-4.0, crystal-reports-2008, windows

i am currently working in C# windows application.Now in want to convert generated  crystal report in to *.pdf format in user specified location by clicking a button.

We already have Export button to convert report to multiple option.But now i want to convert report to *.pdf format by clicking a button

Pls anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method for doing that

```
Report.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "<path>/<name for pdf file>");
```

Please refer the links below

[C# Crystal Reports Export to Pdf](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-export-pdf.htm)

[C# code to export to pdf using Crystal Report](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vscrystalreports/thread/2e6ba358-d88c-4e4f-8b93-f3ae92baeec1/)